# Create video player that can avoid copying youtube links on react

Tags: reactjs, video-streaming

I want to create an online learning website, which requires a video player that can avoid copying YouTube links (I put the video on YouTube). I have found 1 library called medialement.js, but I failed to implement it into react. Does anyone know the solution? thanks.

docs : [medialement](https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement/blob/master/docs/usage.md)

```
import { MediaElementPlayer } from 'mediaelement';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import 'mediaelement';


const VideoPlayers = () => {
  const [player, setPlayer] = useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const options = {
      success: (media, node, instance) => {
        setPlayer(instance);
      },
      error: (media, node) => {
        console.error('Error loading media:', media);
      },
    };
    const player = new MediaElementPlayer('my-video', options);
    setPlayer(player);

  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {player && (
        <video
          id="my-video"
          width="640"
          height="480"
          controls
        >
          <source src="https://example.com/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default VideoPlayers;
```

I have tried to create a component as above but an error appears

Server Error
ReferenceError: Element is not defined

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing `ReferenceError`.
here

```
const player = new MediaElementPlayer('my-video', options);
```

instead of using direct ID you have to pass a reference using `useRef`

```js
const { useState, useRef } = React;

function Home() {
  const videoRef = useRef(null);
  const [player, setPlayer] = useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const options = {
      success: (media, node, instance) => {
        setPlayer(instance);
      },
      error: (media, node) => {
        console.error("Error loading media:", media);
      },
    };
    new MediaElementPlayer(videoRef.current, options);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <video ref={videoRef} width="640" height="480" controls>
        <source
          src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4"
          type="video/mp4"
        />
      </video>
    </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(<Home />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mediaelement@7.0.2/build/mediaelementplayer.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mediaelement@7.0.2/build/mediaelement-and-player.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: for the first way, the result is still element is not defined. for the second way, when I install react-medialement-wrapper, it shows that the dependency is not registered in npm

Comment: Hii @TigoYoga I updated the answer with the demo, The Youtube link is not working, I think for that you have to do research or ask a new question. As per my knowledge, iframe only works.  I hope this answer solves your reference issue and please accept this if it clears yr doubts

Comment: @TigoYoga  have you tried the suggested solutions? If yes please give feedback :)

Comment: sorry but the 'Element is not defined' error still hasn't gone away, even though I've copied your answer